# React - is ok to get a localStorage item to use in the app instead getting this state from redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working in a timezone feature where i can change the timezone for the entire app. This timezone information is needed to make some post / get request.

The point is, i'm using this timezone in the entire app, so i thought to store this state in redux. But i'll lose this state on refresh. Then I'm storing this timezone information in local storage. But i don't know how would be the best practice, cause i need this information to feed my app.

This timezone info is changed on login, and when a different timezone is setted.

1 - Should i discard this redux state and get my info directly from localStorage?

2 - Should i use localStorage to write this redux state, and get info from the redux state instead getting info from localStorage?

3 - Should i do something else?

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use something like [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) which allows you to persist & restore either your full or just selected parts of your store to/from localStorage.